# Android app development: fragment won't show

Tags: android

Can anyone help me here? And yes, I know using the error log like this is bad practice. The fragment below does not produce an exception (yet), but it doesn't show at all:

```
package com.tom.pws;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



public class MAF extends Fragment {
    public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, Bundle args) {
             View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maf, container, false);
             Log.e("reached AGAIN", "yay");
             return view;
    }
}
```

Here's the main activity:

```
package com.tom.pws;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.e("reached", "yay");

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

    MAF maf = new MAF();
    FragmentTransaction fm = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fm.add(R.id.lodsamone, maf);
    fm.commit();
}


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_maf.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text_body"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/lodsamone"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

It seems that OnCreateView will never be reached. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MAF maf = new MAF();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.lodsamone, maf).commit();
```

Is `OnCreateView(...)` correct?

It is

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Comment: Thank you, onCreateView() is being reached, though why replace(...) and not add(...)?

Comment: It's up to you. You can use add (if you have just one Fragment) :) Following this article http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html